# Meaning: their fathers?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Movie: CHIPS

Context: This guy applies for a police job and is getting interviewed and asked why he wants to apply for this job.

**"I learned in couples' therapy that women often marry their fathers, and her dad was a cop.**"

Question: Does this mean women like to marry someone like their father?

Answer (score 2):

From the author's (or speaker's) perspective, women generally prefer to marry someone who is very similar to their own father. This simply means that they prefer someone who has a similar character to their father.

For a woman (or any person, in general), their father will always be the best man in their life. So naturally, they would want their partners to be equally good.

I don't know how this is related to learning English. But that's what this context is about.

Comment: “Girls often marry their boyfriends.” — What would you think if I say this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that sentence. Are you asking me the meaning or the validity, in terms of sentence construction?